# Modify state with multiple nested children in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, nested

I'm trying to build a component which works like a selection tree, but with the possibility for users to edit each row in the selection tree.

Basically, a component where you can keep drilling down to get more details.

The data is structured like a nested object, where an item with drilldown possibilities has a children as per below.

```
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([
    {
      name: "First Tier",
      identifier: "1",
      children: [
        {
          name: "Second Tier",
          identifier: "2",
          children: [
            {
              name: "Third Tier",
              identifier: "3",
              children: [
                {
                  name: "Fourth Tier",
                  identifier: "4",
                  children: [{ name: "Fifth Tier", identifier: "5" }],
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    { name: "Another top tier", identifier: "6" },
    { name: "a Third top tier", identifier: "7" },
  ]);
```

My challenge is that I can't seem to find a way to modify the child and the props as I wish.
As an example, I would like to be able to modify the name of the fifth child to some random name. Note - I wish to be able to modify whatever child, and I will have the identifier available.

As I'm using react, it needs to be done using "useState", which makes it a little bit more tricky according to my understanding.

Any ideas or anyone been through this challenge?

Comment: Recursion may be one option. Have you tried any code till now - and if so, do you mind sharing it with the community so others may be able to help getting it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const findAndUpdate = (id, val, arr) => {
  // find 'arr' element with matching identifier
  const tgtObj = arr.find(
    ({ identifier }) => identifier === id
  );
  if (tgtObj) {             // found identifier, so update the name
    tgtObj.name = val;      // this will mutate the original array passed as argument
  } else {                  // not found, recurse through 'children' array
    arr.filter(el => 'children' in el).forEach(
      ({ children }) => findAndUpdate(id, val, children)
    );
  };
  return arr;               // in all cases, return 'arr' as-is
};

const stateArr = [
    {
      name: "First Tier",
      identifier: "1",
      children: [
        {
          name: "Second Tier",
          identifier: "2",
          children: [
            {
              name: "Third Tier",
              identifier: "3",
              children: [
                {
                  name: "Fourth Tier",
                  identifier: "4",
                  children: [{ name: "Fifth Tier", identifier: "5" }],
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    { name: "Another top tier", identifier: "6" },
    { name: "a Third top tier", identifier: "7" },
  ];

// the 'stateArr' will be mutated by using this method
console.log(
  'find id: 5 and update name: "New Fifth Tier"... ',
  findAndUpdate("5", "New Fifth Tier", stateArr)
);

// to call this using "setCategories", simply try this:
/*
setCategories(prev => findAndUpdate("5", "New Fifth Tier", prev));
*/
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added to the snippet above.

Comment: Thank you! This works. I can't fully get my head to grasp the "return arr". What do you mean by always returning it "as-is"? I gotta say, it was a nice way of using filter and forEach in combination, did not get that far myself

Comment: YW. As you may note: `findAndUpdate` is recursive. The update is done directly on the array passed (ie, the parameter array's object's `name` prop is modified in-place). So, at the end of each recursive call, the parameter array needs to be returned. "as-is" meaning - if we found the identifier & modified the `name`, that updated `name` gets returned; and if otherwise (ie, nothing modified), then too the array gets returned. The array may be either the outer-array, or one of the children-array. It doesn't matter. The last return will always send back the up-to-date outer array.